# Does the definition of a local extrema also satisfy an endpoint in an interval?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

The definition for a local extrema: it must hold that there exists $\epsilon >0$ for $x\in (\epsilon - x_0, x_0 + \epsilon)$ such that $f(x) < f(x_0)$ or $f(x) > f(x_0)$, then $f(x_0)$ is a local maxima or minima.

However we also said that the global maxima or minima can be on an endpoint of the domain of a function. However we also said that every global maximo or minima is also a local maxima or minima, but if the point is an endpoint of the domain, how does that satisfy the upper definition?

Comment: the endpoints are surely extrema for monotonic functions

Comment: @NikosM. So basically I can just use the epsilon neighbourhood as: $(x_0, x_0 + \epsilon)$ and everything else the same, to show it is also a local extrema ?

Comment: Generally, definition should be self-sufficient.

Comment: Extrema, maxima, and minima are plural words.  Their singular forms end with -um

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of local maxima is as follows:

If $f:D \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $x_0 \in D$ then $x_0$ is called a local maxima for $f$ if there exists some $\varepsilon>0$ such that:
$$f(x_0)\ge f(x) , \ (\forall) \ x \in (x_0-\varepsilon,x_0+\varepsilon) \cap D$$